# Wattage in US vs AU/EU household appliances

Tags: resistance, watts, appliances

This oven is listed in both the [US](https://www.breville.com/us/en/products/ovens/bov845.html) and [Australia](https://www.breville.com/au/en/products/ovens/bov845.html). You can see that it's the exact same model (BOV845). Yet if you open the specifications, the only difference is that the US model uses 1800 Watts whereas the Australian/European model uses 2400 Watts. Why might that be? Would it mean that the AU/EU version is capable of outputting more power?

Comment: Although modern US kitchens are required to have two 20 A circuits provided to their countertop surface areas (which means 2400 W maximum for each circuit branch), older homes almost always used 15 A receptacles and 15 A panel breakers and (sadly, almost always in my experience) a single circuit and not two of them. Appliance vendors selling to the US have to keep in mind that history. The 20 A receptacles have a different shaped prong on one side. And those may be in a kitchen, today. So newer construction homes can compete with appliance power specs. But vendors can't only sell to new homes.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

The US model has to have its power limited to the maximum that can be delivered by a standard power socket which is 15 A at 120 V which is 1800 W.

The Australian's have the advantage of higher voltage and can use higher power and get the food ready more quickly. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/NZS_3112) Australian sockets are 230 V, 10 A so that gives a maximum power of 2300 W. (The cooker is pushing it a bit at 2400 W.)

The manufacturers either limit the power by special build or by software control.

Comment: The standard voltage in the US is 120V, though 110V would still be within tolerance I think. Also, the standard current rating for a conventional North American outlet is 15A, though there's also a 20A high-current version. Large devices like an oven may operate on 240V instead of 120V, with special connectors. Not all buildings are wired with a 240V outlet, but many have one in the laundry room for a dryer and I _think_ some also have one for the oven in the kitchen.

Comment: That makes the calculations better, thanks.

Comment: @Hearth, it's a countertop oven, so not going to be designed for 240 V (in the US market).

Comment: What's the reason you couldn't use 15A in Australia? That's 3450W.

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't look at the actual item in question, and just assumed it was a full-size oven.

Comment: @marius: The standard socket isn't rated at 15 A. See the linked article.

Comment: In the US NEC code (2011+): **210.11(C)** *"... two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits shall be provided for all receptacle outlets specified by 21O.52(B)"*, and **210.52(B)(3)** *"... receptacles installed in a kitchen to serve countertop surfaces shall be supplied by not fewer than two small-appliance branch circuits"*. The upshot of which is that kitchens in newer construction are supposed to have two 20 A circuits available. Grandfathered is a 'split-wired receptacle' or just 'split-receptacle' used to help balance loads on each phase. Vendors sell to older 15 A homes, tho.

Comment: Australian sockets are 240V.  european sockets are 220V (but they call it 230V) UK is 240V (but they still call it 230V)

Comment: In Australia 15A needs a special socket, (it looks mostly like a normal Australian 10A socket but the earth slot is taller)  with a 15A socket you can have 3600W

Answer (score 0):

240 V and a typical 16 A in Denmark. The grid decides how much wattage your appliances can consume.

Comment: Hej, cllpse! Welcome to EE.SE. The grid (the big energy network outside the house) does not decide how much power an appliance can consume. The appliance draws as much as it needs / wants. If it exceeds the fuse or circuit breaker rating (in the house) then the fuse or circuit breaker will trip. (Do you mean the "grid" (fuseboard) inside the house?)

Answer (score -2):

What I've found is that in Europe power is the average power while in the USA we use RMS. We use RMS because it more clearly represents accurate information for calculation. So to Cal Europe power to USA power Simply Multiply by 1.0909... and to go from USA to Europe Multiply 0.91666..
This seems to work very closely to the numbers I see.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such thing as RMS power. We use RMS for voltage and current measurements to calculate the quadratic mean which is useful to give the equivalent DC voltage or current that would generate the same power in a resistive load. Power measurement is either instantaneous or average but not RMS. "RMS power" is only used in marketing blurb by manufacturers of audio equipment who should know better.

Comment: RMS is the root mean Squared of the Voltage. EU uses Average Voltage. Therefore there is a difference in advertised power in the EU and the USA.

Comment: Europe does not use average voltage. I live there and am an electrical engineer for many, many years. Where did you read that we use average voltage and that there is a difference in advertised power in the EU and the USA?